# How to recursively increase state, whilst using async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, recursion

Like the title suggests.
If I manually trigger btnClick, value increases unless it's at limit.
When I do it recursively it never gets past 1 increase.

I'm assuming it's due to a re-render but I can't figure out how to get around it.

```
export const AsyncTest = ()=>{
    const [value,setValue] = useState(-1);
    const [limit] = useState(5);

    const btnClick = async ()=>{
        const test = await increase();
        // Call it's self if value < limit
        if (test === false) {
            btnClick();
        } else {
            // Code that can happen after this has finished
        }
        
    }

    const increase = ()=>{
        return new Promise (result =>{
            window.setTimeout(()=>{
                let valueNew = value + 1;
                if (valueNew <= limit){
                    setValue(valueNew);
                    result(false);
                } else {
                    result(true);
                }
            }, 1000);
        })
    }
    return (
        <button id="asyncTestBtn" onClick={btnClick}>{value}</button>
    )
}
```

Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Comment: It's due to the new render, but even if it weren't you would have a closure over the value state. You can use a `useEffect` dependent on `value` to trigger further increases.

Comment: The `const value` never changes between the recursive calls